# Replace subqueries in where statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I've built a query that intends to find products (`products` table) with both a 'used' offer and a 'new' offer, and get the lowest price for each. A product can have multiple offers (`link_prices` table). The offer's condition is determined by the name of the merchant (`merchants` table): a name without `used` and `occasion` is a 'new' offer, a name with `used` is a 'used' offer.

Here's a sample of the tables (PostgreSQL):

```
merchants

+----+---------------+
| id |     name      |
+----+---------------+
|  1 | amazon_used   |
|  2 | ebay_location |
|  3 | amazon        |
|  4 | target        |
|  5 | target_used   |
+----+---------------+

link_prices

+----+-------------+------------+-------+
| id | merchant_id | product_id | price |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+
|  1 |           1 |          1 |       |
|  2 |           1 |          2 |    20 |
|  3 |           4 |          2 |    30 |
|  4 |           5 |          2 |    5  |
|  5 |           2 |          3 |    10 |
|  6 |           1 |          4 |    80 |
|  7 |           1 |          3 |   100 |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+
```

In this case, I'm expecting my query to return

```
+------------+----------------+---------------+
| product_id | min_used_price | min_new_price |
+------------+----------------+---------------+
|          2 |              5 |            30 |
+------------+----------------+---------------+
```

I've got the following query to work but I feel like I shouldn't need to use subqueries to achieve this. I just can't work my head around it. Any help would be appreciated to optimize this query.

```
      SELECT products.id, 
      MIN(CASE WHEN merchants.name ILIKE '%used%' THEN link_prices.price END) as min_used_price,
      MIN(CASE WHEN merchants.name NOT ILIKE '%used%' THEN link_prices.price END) as min_new_price
      FROM products
      INNER JOIN link_prices ON link_prices.product_id = products.id
      INNER JOIN merchants ON merchants.id = link_prices.merchant_id
      WHERE 
      products.id IN (
        SELECT products.id
        FROM products 
        INNER JOIN link_prices ON link_prices.product_id = products.id
        INNER JOIN merchants ON merchants.id = link_prices.merchant_id
        AND merchants.name ILIKE '%used%' 
        AND link_prices.price IS NOT NULL 
        AND link_prices.price <> 0
      )
      AND products.id IN (
        SELECT products.id
        FROM products 
        INNER JOIN link_prices ON link_prices.product_id = products.id
        INNER JOIN merchants ON merchants.id = link_prices.merchant_id
        AND merchants.name NOT ILIKE '%used%' 
        AND merchants.name NOT ILIKE '%location%'
        AND link_prices.price IS NOT NULL 
        AND link_prices.price <> 0
      )
      GROUP BY products.id
```

Thanks a ton!

Comment: Does your query as it is return correct results?

Comment: Yes it does, this is more to improve my knowledge of SQL and maybe performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description makes this sound like conditional aggregation:

```
select lp.product_id,
       min(lp.price) filter (where m.name like '%used') as min_used_price,
       min(lp.price) filter (where m.name not like '%used') as min_new_price
from merchants m join
     link_prices lp
     on lp.merchant_id = m.id
group by lp.product_id;
```

You sample query is much more complicated and has conditions that are not mentioned in the text of the question.  But I think this structure will work for what you want to do.

Comment: Perfect ! This solved my issue and is way easier than what I had done. I added a `having` clause to remove some lines that had price = 0.